# Function is not behaving as intended. Why?

Tags: javascript

Sorry for not being more precise on the title.

https://jsfiddle.net/ptxsha6m/1/

```
<script>
var theID = document.getElementById('result1');

function change(){
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox');
    var chekboxInputs = Array.from(checkboxes).map(a => a.querySelector('input'));
    var allAreUnselected = chekboxInputs.every(function(elem){
       return !elem.checked;
    });
    if(allAreUnselected){
       chekboxInputs.forEach(function(input){
          Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("." + input.getAttribute("rel"))).forEach(function(theID){
              theID.style.background = 'blue';
          });
       });
    }
    else {
      chekboxInputs.forEach(function(input){
          Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("." + input.getAttribute("rel"))).forEach(function(theID){
            theID.style.background = input.checked ? 'red' : 'gray';
          });
       });
    }
}
change();
</script>
```

Basically, as I wrote, it should change the div#id with the background yellow to red once a checkbox is selected. But for some reason it insists in targeting the div with class only.

I know there must be something wrong with the logic, there's a few things that I can tell but others I don't understand. For example, at "if(allAreUnselected)" shouldn't it set the background of the yellow box to blue? Since they *are* all unselected?

All I'm trying to achieve is be able to manipulate the div# inside the function. Any help?

Thanks

Comment: "Sorry for not being more precise on the title." You can edit the title.

Answer (score 5):

Early in your script you capture the DOM element you're talking about in a variable named `theID`:

```
var theID = document.getElementById('result1');
```

Later on, where you're changing the color of the elements, you're using an anonymous function in a forEach, which has a parameter *also* named `theID`:

```
(/* lots of code */).forEach(function(theID){
    theID.style.background = 'blue'
});
```

That parameter name masks the variable defined earlier, so when you use `theID` inside that function it refers to each of the forEach elements instead of the #result1 element -- and you wind up never attempting to change the color of #result1.

If you want to change the color of that container, either use a different parameter name, so the variable isn't masked by it:

```
(/* lots of code */).forEach(function(foo){
    foo.style.background = 'blue'
    theID.style.background = // your logic here for deciding what color #result1 should be
});
```

...or do it outside the anonymous function:

```
if(allAreUnselected){
   theID.style.background = 'blue';
   chekboxInputs.forEach(function(input){
     (/* lots of code */).forEach(function(theID){   // (I'd still change that parameter name, though, because masked variables are confusing)
```

Comment: Wow, thank you! I understand how it all functions better now and I think I can work with it. :)

Answer (score 0):

In line 41 what you think is the `theID` variable is wrong. In this case the variable `theID` will be shadowed from the variable that the `forEach` function passes as argument to the callback function(theID){..}.

`forEach` passes each item in the array as argument to the function you declare on each iteration. Try to change the name of this variable, ex. `...forEach(function(chekboxInput) { chekboxInput.style.background = 'blue';}` nothing will change.

From here the `theID` is not anymore the div with id=result1 but one of the elements in the `chekboxInputs` that you are iterating on.

See also the answer from Daniel Beck.